# Cannot load htmlAudioElement audio on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, google-chrome, html5-audio

I found out the following code works on Desktop browsers and Android but not on my iPad.

```
document.onclick = () => {
    const testAudio = document.createElement("AUDIO");
    testAudio.oncanplaythrough = () => {
      console.log("CAN PLAY!");
      testAudio.play();
    }
    console.log("LOADING AUDIO...");
    testAudio.src = "https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3";
}
```

When I see the console log on my iPad's Chrome inspector, it just prints "LOADING AUDIO..." and never prints "CAN PLAY". It also didn't work on my iPad's Safari.

What would be the reason and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile browsers are generally a bit more hesitant to load something but calling [`load()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/load) should force them to do so.

```
document.onclick = () => {
    const testAudio = document.createElement("AUDIO");
    testAudio.oncanplaythrough = () => {
      console.log("CAN PLAY!");
      testAudio.play();
    }
    console.log("LOADING AUDIO...");
    testAudio.src = "https://www.soundhelix.com/examples/mp3/SoundHelix-Song-1.mp3";

    testAudio.load();
}
```